# How I can invoke js script from django view?

Tags: django, django-views

In a view I have a condition that should invoke js script declared in template. Is there any way to do it?

```
view.py
@login_required
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def client_get_resources(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' && request.profile.entitiy == None:
         return ##here I should invoke askForData()
```

template.html

```
<script>
function askForData(){
  console.log(1)
}
</script>
```

Comment: What do you want to do? This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Plus your question also lacks a lot in details, one could say it is almost a "give me the codes" or a "homework problem".

Comment: could you please show some code example?